# F# is it possible to "upcast" discriminated union value to a "superset" union?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Let's say there are two unions where one is a strict subset of another.

```
type Superset =
| A of int
| B of string
| C of decimal

type Subset =
| A of int
| B of string
```

Is it possible to automatically upcast a Subset value to Superset value *without resorting to explicit pattern matching?* Like this:

```
let x : Subset = A 1
let y : Superset = x // this won't compile :(
```

Also it's ideal if Subset type was altered so it's no longer a subset then compiler should complain:

```
type Subset =
| A of int
| B of string
| D of bool // - no longer a subset of Superset!
```

I believe it's not possible to do but still worth asking (at least to understand why it's impossible)

**WHY I NEED IT**

I use this style of set/subset typing extensively in my domain to restrict valid parameters in different states of entities / make invalid states non-representable and find the approach very beneficial, the only downside is very tedious upcasting between subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sorry, no

Sorry, but this is not possible. Take a look at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-decompiled/#unions — you'll see that F# compiles discriminated unions to .NET classes, each one separate from each other with no common ancestors (apart from `Object`, of course). The compiler makes no effort to try to identify subsets or supersets between different DUs. If it did work the way you suggested, it would be a breaking change, because the only way to do this would be to make the subset DU a base class, and the superset class its derived class with an extra property. And that would make the following code change behavior:

```
type PhoneNumber =
| Valid of string
| Invalid

type EmailAddress =
| Valid of string
| ValidButOutdated of string
| Invalid

let identifyContactInfo (info : obj) =
    // This came from external code we don't control, but it should be contact info
    match (unbox obj) with
    | :? PhoneNumber as phone -> // Do something
    | :? EmailAddress as email -> // Do something
```

Yes, this is bad code and should be written differently, but it illustrates the point. Under current compiler behavior, if `identifyContactInfo` gets passed a `EmailAddress` object, the `:? PhoneNumber` test will fail and so it will enter the second branch of the match, and treat that object (correctly) as an email address. If the compiler were to guess supersets/subsets based on DU names as you're suggesting here, then `PhoneNumber` would be considered a subset of `EmailAddress` and so would become its base class. And then when this function received an `EmailAddress` object, the `:? PhoneNumber` test would succeed (because an instance of a derived class can always be cast to the type of its base class). And then the code would enter the *first* branch of the match expression, and your code might then try to send a text message to an email address.

### But wait...

What you're trying to do might be achievable by pulling out the subsets into their own DU category:

```
type AorB =
| A of int
| B of string

type ABC =
| AorB of AorB
| C of decimal

type ABD =
| AorB of AorB
| D of bool
```

Then your match expressions for an `ABC` might look like:

```
match foo with
| AorB (A num) -> printfn "%d" num
| AorB (B s) -> printfn "%s" s
| C num -> printfn "%M" num
```

And if you need to pass data between an `ABC` and an `ABD`:

```
let (bar : ABD option) =
    match foo with
    | AorB data -> Some (AorB data)
    | C _ -> None
```

That's not a huge savings if your subset has only two common cases. But if your subset is a dozen cases or so, being able to pass those dozen around as a unit makes this design attractive.